# С помощью High Resolution Time API определить время поиска каждого простого числа

Tags: javascript

```
function receivedWorkerMessage(event) {

    var message = event.data;

    if (message.type === "PrimeList") {
        var primes = message.data;

        // Show the prime number list on the page.
        var primeList = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
            primeList += primes[i];
            if (i !== primes.length - 1) primeList += "<br>";
        }
        var displayList = document.getElementById("primeContainer");
        displayList.innerHTML = primeList;

        if (primeList.length === 0) {
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = "Не найдено ни одного результата.";
        } else {
            var notification = new Notification("Результаты здесь!");
            statusDisplay.innerHTML = "Результаты здесь!";
        }
        searchButton.disabled = false;
    } else if (message.type === "Progress") {
        statusDisplay.innerHTML = message.data + "% выполнено ...";
    }
}
```

У меня есть функция, которая выводит найдены простые числа.
Как мне через High Resolution Time и метод `performance.now()`определить время поиска каждого простого числа.

*полностью код https://codepen.io/kodeme/pen/LYPodeB*

Comment: ваш алгоритм не оптимален. что ж это, искать простые числа до 2 млн. дольше минуны. Простые числа ищутся быстрее.

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: мне важно определить время поиска каждого простого числа.
не пойму как правильно использовать метод performance.now()

Comment: но задача все равно некорректная. Вопрос не в том сколько нужно времени (меньше секунды). Вопрос в том, сколько нужно ОЗУ чтобы найти простые числа.

Comment: Попытался создать комнату в чате, чтобы не здесь обсудить это. но у меня не получается выслать инвайт в эту комнату

Comment: Дело в том, что для поиска простых чисел производительность не нужна, нужно только много оперативки или SSD с большим ресурсом, чтобы хранить массив этих простых чисел.